# Jupyter Notebook "Password or token" issue

Tags: jupyter-notebook, passwords, token

I am trying to open the jupyter in the firefox since I've always opened it in chrome. and what should I do to tackle this password? Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you start a jupyter server locally, you type `jupyter notebook` in a cmd console. And then you get an output similar to this:

[image]

Jupyter should then redirect you to `localhost:8888` in your browser. If it asks you for your token/password, you can find it in the console, last line. In the case of this image, the token is 5fe355c8a0e68158fed7b498805097811951f519809d7b44